# CString Format VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cstring

Using the code below sometimes the text variable contains a very huge and strange number, something like "1552505576255083400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000". 
A "0.000" string is expected.

I've also tryed with a basic dialog app and execute these two lines of code in the "OnInitDialog()"
I'm using VS 2013. With VS 2003 seems that it works correctly.

can somebody tell me why?

```
CString text;
text.Format(_T("%.3f"), 0);
```

Comment: The problem is that `0` is not a `double` which is what the format specifier `%.3f` expects.  Try passing `0.0` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a bug. The `%f` format specifies requires a floating point number and you specify an integer. To fix the bug, change the `0` to `0.0`.